# ExpressJS HTML encoder

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have been running into issues with my wysiwyg html editor where the content and formatting (bold, italic) would display unformatted and with the appropriate tags (`<strong></strong><i></i>`), but when I looked at the source code I would see that the tags are not html encoded. It appears that this is why all of my content being displayed in my views does not show correctly. Does anyone know of packages that can fix this information? Or is there a good work around that encodes the content before being saved to my database?

Here is what the code looks like displayed:

[image: Code Displayed]

Here is what the source code looks like:

[image: Source code]

Here is where the content is posted:

```
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.5/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid grid-pad">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <h1>Blog Create</h1>


            <form action="/admin/posts/create" method="POST">
                Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
                Author: 
                    <select name="author">
                        <option value="Author">Test</option>
                    </select><br>
                Tagline: <input type="text" maxlength="160" name="tagline"><br>
                Content:<br>
                <textarea name="content" id="blog-editor" rows="10" cols="80">

                </textarea><br>
                Tags: <input type="text" name="tags"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

        <script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="blog-editor"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.

                CKEDITOR.replace( 'blog-editor' );
                CKEDITOR.config.entities = false;   
CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek= false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin= false;  
CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push = '/<\#[\s\S]*#\#>/g';



    </script>


    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

model schema:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;



var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title: String,
        blogUrl: String,
        author: String,
        tagline: String,
        category: String,
        content: String,
        tags: { type: String, lowercase: true },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});

BlogPostSchema.post('init', function (post) {
    var date = new Date(post.date || Date.now() );
    post.dateString = date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

});

BlogPostSchema.plugin( mongoosePaginate );

var Blogpost = mongoose.model("Blogpost", BlogPostSchema);



module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');

router.route('/admin/posts/create')

    // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            console.log("New instance");

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                });

        }) // END POST method


        .get(function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/blogpost-create');
        });

function getSearchCriteria(params) {
      return {
          blogUrl: params.blogpost_blogUrl
      };
}
```

Comment: You don't show the code where you output the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the templating. In EJS the way to escape all HTML tags is to use `<%- code %>` and not `<%= code %>`